# Counting unique login using Map Reduce

Tags: mapreduce

Let say I have a very big log file with this kind of format( based on where a user login )

```
UserId1 , New York
UserId1 , New Jersey
UserId2 , Oklahoma
UserId3 , Washington DC
....
userId999999999, London
```

Note that UserId1 logged in New York first and then he flied to New Jersey and logged again from there.

If I need to get how many unique user login (means 2 login will same userid considered as 1 login), how should I map and reduce it?

My initial plan is that I want to map it first to this kind of format :

```
UserId1, 1
UserId1, 1
UserId2, 1
UserId3, 1
```

And then reduce it to

```
UserId1, 2
UserId2, 1
UserId3, 1
```

But would this cause the output to be still big in number (Especially if common behaviour of user is to login 1 or 2 times a day ). Or is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do map-reduce.

For example, you have 10000 lines of data, but you can only process 1000 lines of data in a time.

Then, process 1000 lines of data for 10 times.

If the sum of lines of the 10 processing's result > 1000:

do the above step again.

else:

use set directly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making use of a custom key in the map phase. You can refer the tutorial [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#keytypes) for writing and using custom keys. The custom key should have two parts 1) userid 2)placeid. So essentially in the mapper phase you are doing this.

```
emit(<userid, place>, 1)
```

In the reduce phase, you just have to access the key and emit the two parts of the key separately.